# Preserve lifetime of an argument in another object

Tags: rust

I have a struct `X` with 2 fields `owned` and `refed`, used to hold ownership and reference of numbers passed in by the `insert` function.

```
fn main() {
    struct X<'a> {
        owned: Vec<i32>,
        refed: Vec<&'a i32>
    }

    impl<'a> X<'a> {
        fn insert(&mut self, n: i32) {
            self.owned.push(n);
            self.refed.push(&n);
        }
    }

    let mut x = X { owned: vec![], refed: vec![] };
    x.insert(1);
}
```

[fiddle](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Bfeature(box_syntax%2C%20box_patterns)%5D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20Some(box%205)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20match%20b%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Some(box%20n)%20if%20n%20%3C%200%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Box%20contains%20negative%20number%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20n)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Some(box%20n)%20if%20n%20%3E%3D%200%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Box%20contains%20non-negative%20number%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20n)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20None%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22No%20box%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_%20%3D%3E%20unreachable!()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&version=nightly)

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
error: `n` does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:10:30
   |
10 |             self.refed.push(&n);
   |                              ^ does not live long enough
11 |         }
   |         - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on unknown free region bounded by scope CodeExtent(36/CallSiteScope { fn_id: NodeId(24), body_id: NodeId(68) })...

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I'm surprised that the compiler thinks `n` will no longer be available after the function ends, even though its ownership was already transferred and extended. So how do we get around this?

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicate, the compiler is specifically complaining because you are trying to take a reference to the stack-allocated `i32` that was passed as an argument. You are **not** taking a reference to the `i32` that was stored in the vector. `i32` is a [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) type. The linked duplicate is the answer you would run into next, once you took the reference to yourself ^_^.

Comment: @Shepmaster, got it. Thanks for taking your time to explain this.